# How to take a screenshot of remote Linux desktop from local macbook

Tags: linux, macbook, vnc, screenshot

I am on a local macbook (OS Catalina 10.15.7--not sure if it matters), and I am accessing a remote Linux machine through VNC.

How can I take a screenshot of the remote Linux window (accessed from local macbook through VNC)?  I tried the screenshot hotkeys like SHIFT-COMMAND_3, SHIFT_COMMAND_4.  While those hotkeys work when my active window is a local window of the macbook, it didn't do anything (no response) when my active window is the remote Linux window.

Is it the screenshot hotkey supposed to work for remote window?  If so, what did I miss and what do I need to do?  If not, how can I take a screenshot of the remote window?  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Local screenshots work for Apple Remote Desktop & Windows RDC. Maybe the remote machine uses those key commands for something else? Maybe try Cmd/Shift/5 instead & see what happens - at least see if you get the interface. Worst comes to the worst, just drop the VNC connection to the background while you take the shot.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried Cmd-Shift-5 and nothing happened---I didn't see the interface come up.  Again Cmd-Shift-5 also works if the active window is local instead of remote.   What do you mean by "drop the VNC connection to the background"?  I have to make the remote window active in order to take a screenshot of it, right?

Comment: The remote is probably stealing the keys. Similar happens with certain key combos remoting to Mac or Win. You have to either change your local key commands or those of every machine you remote into, which isn't really practical. Why does it need to be active? As far as your local Mac is concerned, it's just a window with an image in it.